# Best package for typesetting critical edition of Greek texts: ednotes, reledpar, reledmac, or ekdosis?

Tags: reledmac, endnotes, reledpar

I know of several packages designed for producing critical editions: `ednotes`, `reledpar`, `reledmac`, and, most recently, `ekdosis`. What are the relative strengths and weaknesses of these packages for producing critical editions of ancient Greek (or other) texts? (E.g., initial process of producing the content, typesetting facility and flexibility, compatibility with other packages.)

The documentation of each package offers some idea of why to choose one over the other (`ekdosis`, for example, stresses its compatibility with TEI-compliant XML output), but I am hoping to hear from someone who has experience producing critical editions (or who wrote/maintains one of these packages) and so can speak to the advantages of one or more of these packages (or another package) in practice.

To be clear, I am including below a screenshot of a page from a critical edition of the sort I am describing (from Ihor Ševčenko, ed., *Chronographiae quae Theophanis continuati nomine fertur liber quo Vita Basilii Imperatoris amplectitur*, Berlin 2011). It demonstrates some of the features required: marginal line numbers, page numbers of other editions, folio numbers of manuscripts, multiple footnote registers that are keyed to line numbers rather than using a footnote hook, etc., as well as parallel translation.

[image: Greek critical edition example]

Comment: I think reledmac could answer to your problem. To be clear, as reledmac maintener, my opinion is that ekdosis is more XML-Compliant, but reledmac has more typographical option (except if you require 3 columns or more parallele typesetting)

Comment: Unfortunately, `ednotes` is not compatible with parallel typesetting.  `ekdosis` requires LuaLaTeX while `reledmac` is compatible with all typesetting engines.

Comment: I've noticed that there is a [helpful review](https://ride.i-d-e.de/issues/issue-11/reledmac/) by Andrew N. J. Dunning addressing this question with respect to `reledmac`.

Comment: Thank you. Hoping to be forgiven for this shameless bit of autopromotion, I would also mention [this contribution](https://jdmdh.episciences.org/6536) to a [special issue](https://jdmdh.episciences.org/page/collecting-preserving-and-disseminating-endangered-cultural-heritage-for-new-understandings-and-multilingual-approaches) published in JDMDH (2020).

Comment: Not at all shameless, it's exactly what I was asking for -- thank you!

Comment: From those articles, I gather that: (1) `ekdosis` and `reledmac` are both being actively maintained/developed, while `ednotes` is not; (2) `reledmac` emphasizes typesetting of the apparatus (including the possibility of overlapping lemmas) while leaving the structure/contents of lemmas etc. and even the customizations of human-readable macros (for things like variants, etc.) up to the individual user, whereas `ekdosis` focuses on providing those macros, making it perhaps less flexible but more readily usable "out of the box" (provided one learns its system); (3) `ekdosis` does XML.

Comment: With `ekdosis` the package essentially writes the lemmas and other apparatus text based on data that the user has encoded using macros (thus facilitating simultaneous production of XML output). With `reledmac` the *user* writes the lemmas and apparatus text, which has the simultaneous advantage and disadvantage of not standardizing how this is done.

Comment: With ekdosis, I would put this as follows: the mandatory arguments of commands such as `\lem` or `\rdg` give the user full control over what is to be encoded as variation (otherwise TEI xml output would be impossible), while the optional arguments of the same commands give control over what is to be printed—or 'painted' in a manner of speaking—in the apparatus criticus.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Regarding overlapping lemmas, see [here](https://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/TC.html#TCAPPS) for the theoretical approach.  Such a passage as `[a [b a'] b']` may be encoded from `a` to `b'` and split into pieces.  The apparatus in print is then written by means of the optional arguments.  Another way would be to use pointers as in the case of the `\note` command described in sect. 6 of the documentation.  This is being looked into.